# Can you prevent the first column of a table from sorting?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I use the below code to sort my table on my site [LBRYnomics](https://lbrynomics.com). It excludes the table header when sorting, but I also want to exclude the tables first column (Channel Rank) as highlighted in red. Is there a way to do this?

Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks!

**Current Code:**

```
const getCellValue = (tr, idx) => tr.children[idx].innerText || tr.children[idx].textContent;
const comparer = (idx, asc) => (a, b) => ((v1, v2) => (v1 === null) - (v2 === null) || (isFinite(v1) && isFinite(v2) ?
v1 - v2 : v1.toString().localeCompare(v2))) (getCellValue(asc ? a : b, idx), getCellValue(asc ? b : a, idx));

document.querySelectorAll('th').forEach(th => th.addEventListener('click', (() => {
const table = th.closest('table');
Array.from(table.querySelectorAll('tr:nth-child(n+2)'))

.sort(comparer(Array.from(th.parentNode.children).indexOf(th), this.asc = !this.asc))
.forEach(tr => table.appendChild(tr));
})));
```

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to force channel rank column to stay the same when other columns are sorted, or just have it not sort by rank when it's clicked, or can you clarify what it is you want to achieve?  This would force it always to be 1-200: `.forEach((tr,i) => {tr.querySelector('td.rank').innerText=i+1+'';table.appendChild(tr)});`  but that doesn't seem like something you'd want.

Comment: Yes, correct. So it always stays 1 - 200, not matter how the other columns are sorted.

Comment: Because the `<td>` is within the `<tr>`, and you are actually appending the entire `<tr>` element from a sorted array, it's not possible without overwriting the `<td>`'s content to simulate order like the snippet I have above, or keep track of all the `<td>` elemnets and reinsert them into the rows in order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it with only HTML/CSS, or have that column behave independently, you will have to create two inline tables and have them placed side by side, one for the ranks and one for your data.  Probably is not difficult to do.
It is not otherwise possible, because `td.rank` is a child enclosed within the `tr` element, and rearranging the position of the `tr` will move the `td` with it within the hierarchy.
If you want something more flexible you could use css flex-grid and simulate a table without being bound by the hierarchy of elements a table row structure requires.

Two methods that involve replacing in sequential order.

Replace `td.rank`s text with sequential numbers 1-200.  Can also use `.childNodes[0]`

```
const getCellValue = (tr, idx) => tr.children[idx].innerText || tr.children[idx].textContent;
const comparer = (idx, asc) => (a, b) => ((v1, v2) => (v1 === null) - (v2 === null) || (isFinite(v1) && isFinite(v2) ?
v1 - v2 : v1.toString().localeCompare(v2))) (getCellValue(asc ? a : b, idx), getCellValue(asc ? b : a, idx));

document.querySelectorAll('th').forEach(th => th.addEventListener('click', (() => {
const table = th.closest('table');
Array.from(table.querySelectorAll('tr:nth-child(n+2)'))

.sort(comparer(Array.from(th.parentNode.children).indexOf(th), this.asc = !this.asc))
.forEach((tr,i) => {tr.querySelector('.rank').innerText=i+1+'';table.appendChild(tr)});
})));
```

Storing `td.rank`s in an array, and replaceChild the row in order.

```
const getCellValue = (tr, idx) => tr.children[idx].innerText || tr.children[idx].textContent;
const comparer = (idx, asc) => (a, b) => ((v1, v2) => (v1 === null) - (v2 === null) || (isFinite(v1) && isFinite(v2) ?
v1 - v2 : v1.toString().localeCompare(v2))) (getCellValue(asc ? a : b, idx), getCellValue(asc ? b : a, idx));

document.querySelectorAll('th').forEach(th => th.addEventListener('click', (() => {
const table = th.closest('table');
const col1 = table.querySelectorAll('.rank:nth-child(n+2)');
Array.from(table.querySelectorAll('tr:nth-child(n+2)'))

.sort(comparer(Array.from(th.parentNode.children).indexOf(th), this.asc = !this.asc))
.forEach((tr,i) => {
   tr.replaceChild(col1[i],tr.childNodes[0]);
   table.appendChild(tr);
});
})));
```

Comment: That's pretty smart and works perfectly. Thanks for the extra info too!